# How to handle Facebook/Google login in android app having lot of activities?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-activity, facebook-login

I am new to authenticating through social networks on android so pardon me. I created activity with which i can login through facebook and google. I am planning to do this : user comes first time, ask him to login through Google or Facebook, once he does, let him go to other activities. How do i handle scenario when user closed and restart my app. I want my app to work both offline and online.

**Method 1** : I am planning to store a bit in my sqlite DB which notes that whether user signed in through any social network, if he done then go ahead. Don't open login page multiple times and directly give user access to other pages. Problem with this approach is that if i want user to publish on his wall then i need to get him log in again before publishing (if session token expires). Rest seems fine. Also i will provide him a sign out button with which i will clear this bit for next time login.

What do you guys think about this approach? How other people does this in their apps with multiple activities. Assuming this approach works fine if we don't need to access facebook/google again and just need to get basic user data to let him login. Drawback, even he remove my app from his facebook/google account, i give him full access until he logout.

**Method 2**: Always on app start i check if facebook has session.isOpen() or myGoogleClient.isConnected(). If any of this gives true, i let user go in my app. Make sure with what network user logged in and show him log out button of that network. This check will only come when user restart his app. Once user login, does he always logged in or he see lot of login pages? I feel this approach is better.

Do i need to check for session open condition on each activity when transactioning through activities?

Any suggestions what approach is used by different apps. I want my app to be accessed for data in offline mode, but still let user access online feature when he is online.

Even when he is logged in with google, i want him to publish on his wall with facebook login, so will ask him to do so if he clicks on publish button, this way at times i have both logins and will chose any on them.

Please show me directions. I tried to find this on net and reached to above conclusions, but not able to finalize on right approach.

Comment: Hey Mitesh, I see that you are Using GoogleApiClient in your app. Can you please tell me what happens with your app if there is no working internet ?

Comment: In my case GoogleApiClient fails to connect (if I am using scope Plus.Scope_profile or Plus.Scope_login) and it clears that account for my package, I have to login again but if I change the scope to 'email' or 'profile', its not the case. Now In case their is no network, GoogleApiClient still gets connected. I am really very confused in it. Can you help me with it ?

Comment: I am going with Method 1 as that is a easy way and i fount it mentioned at different places. I use login, just to fetch user data only once. Not want user to see login issues when he is offline.